# trying to work with arrays in java but don't know what i am doing wrong

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to achieve the following structure,

```
100    200    300    400    500    600    700    800
200    400    600    800  1,000  1,200  1,400  1,600
```

I tried with the following code but I can't make it work.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cols = 5;
        int rows = 4;
        int number = 100;
        int [][] doublearr = new int [rows][cols];


        for (int i = 0; i < doublearr.length ;i ++){
            for(int j=0; j < doublearr[i].length; j++){
                    doublearr[0][0] = number;
                    doublearr[i][j] = doublearr[0][0] *( j+1);
                    System.out.print("\t" + doublearr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    }
```

This is the output i am getting for this.

```
100 200 300 400 500
100 200 300 400 500
100 200 300 400 500
100 200 300 400 500
```

I really appreciate if any one can point me in the right direction. thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Do you really want to set `doublearr[0][0] = number` in each run of the loop? This seems to be a one-time initialization that should be done once before the loop starts.

Comment: 2) You should separate filling the array and printing the array (which means having two different loops).

Comment: i tried the first step and the result is the same, will do the second step as you mentioned and will see if that will work.

Comment: Please update the code in your question with your latest attempt and the output it produces.

Comment: i have tried both both steps suggested by -Seelenvirtuose but looks like it doesn't change any thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to print double of the above column then you will need to do a small change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < doublearr.length ;i ++){
    for(int j=0; j < doublearr[i].length; j++){
            doublearr[0][0] = number;
            doublearr[i][j] = doublearr[0][0] *( j+1);
            System.out.print("\t" + doublearr[i][j]);
    }
  number*=2;  // add this line
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: this code works except one thing, in the out put  for the second row after 300 it should be 400 , 500 and so on but instead its adding 300. 
100 200 300 400 500
 200 400 600 800 1000
 300 600 900 1200 1500
 400 800 1200 1600 2000,

Comment: @isfan i tried with cols 5 and rows 4 it is working as expected double of the above column is printed

Comment: thanks Ravik what i want to achieve is in the second row at index 0 it will be double of first row's index 0, lets say 100 is at index 0 in first rows column 1, so in second row it should increment like this  200 300 400 instead of 200 400 600. again appreciate your help.

Comment: @isfan pls add minimum 4 rows sample output to your question so I can understand better and give correct options

Comment: It's all good ravid thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your column into `8` and row into `2` because your output value is `8 * 2 = 16`. Your equation is `doublearr[0][0] * (j + 1)`

**If your equation is `doublearr[0][0] * (j + 1)`:**

**1.** 100 * (0 + 1) = 100

**2.** 100 * (1 + 1) = 200

**3.** 100 * (2 + 1) = 300

**4.** 100 * (3 + 1) = 400

**5.** 100 * (4 + 1) = 500

**6.** 100 * (5 + 1) = 600

**7.** 100 * (6 + 1) = 700

**8.** 100 * (7 + 1) = 800

**9.** 100 * (0 + 1) = 100

**10.** 100 * (1 + 1) = 200

**11.** 100 * (2 + 1) = 300

**12.** 100 * (3 + 1) = 400

**13.** 100 * (4 + 1) = 500

**14.** 100 * (5 + 1) = 600

**15.** 100 * (6 + 1) = 700

**16.** 100 * (7 + 1) = 800

**If equation change to `doublearr[0][0] * (j + 1) * (i + 1)`:**

**1.** 100 * (0 + 1)  * (0 + 1)= 100

**2.** 100 * (1 + 1) * (0 + 1)= 200

**3.** 100 * (2 + 1) * (0 + 1)= 300

**4.** 100 * (3 + 1) * (0 + 1)= 400

**5.** 100 * (4 + 1) * (0 + 1)= 500

**6.** 100 * (5 + 1) * (0 + 1)= 600

**7.** 100 * (6 + 1) * (0 + 1)= 700

**8.** 100 * (7 + 1) * (0 + 1)= 800

**9.** 100 * (0 + 1) * (1 + 1)= 200

**10.** 100 * (1 + 1) * (1 + 1)= 400

**11.** 100 * (2 + 1) * (1 + 1)= 600

**12.** 100 * (3 + 1) * (1 + 1)= 800

**13.** 100 * (4 + 1) * (1 + 1)= 1000

**14.** 100 * (5 + 1) * (1 + 1)= 1200

**15.** 100 * (6 + 1) * (1 + 1)= 1400

**16.** 100 * (7 + 1) * (1 + 1)= 1600

Here down is my code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int cols = 8;
    int rows = 2;
    int number = 100;
    int [][] doublearr = new int [rows][cols];


    for (int i = 0; i < doublearr.length ;i ++){
        for(int j=0; j < doublearr[i].length; j++){
                doublearr[0][0] = number;
                doublearr[i][j] = doublearr[0][0] * (j + 1) * (i + 1);
                System.out.print(" " + doublearr[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks a million really appreciate your help.

Comment: @isfan Don't forget to accept answer if you think it is right

Comment: not sure how to accept answer, is there any option on the page to accept answers.

Comment: Yes, you can see top right side  `right answer` symbol just click on it. behind vote count

Comment: thanks Bhanej just saw it.

Comment: you can not accept answer click on this buttton

Comment: click on my accout `right button`. you click on `Ravik` account button